# Mongodb and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, mongodb

Our db group is looking at placing our mongodb server instances on the same servers that host sql server.     Our SQL foot print is fairly large with a good dozen dbs larger than 200gb in total space in a sql cluster availability group setup.   The mongodb server setup is fairly small and the data is less than a gigabyte in size but we will set this up in a 3 node setup across 3 machines used for the sql server setup.

Has anybody had any bad experiences with this kind of setup or any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a horrible, horrible idea.

Not only are IO patterns drastically different between the two applications, but maintenance schedules etc. will be completely different as well. Why would you fate-share two completely different critical database applications if you could avoid it? Databases fare best if they have full use of the resources available on any one machine.

Put your Mongo cluster on different VMs. Doing so will simplify your life significantly, and will make troubleshooting and maintenance much easier,.

Comment: Thanks,  I do agree with you but I wanted to see if there was an definitive scenarios that would make this a bad idea like they are proven to be incompatible on the same server or one will drag down the performance of the other.